# Word Macro Remove Rows from Table If Cell Empty

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to run a Macro that will check a selected table for empty cells in column 2, and if there are empty cells, delete that row.

```
Sub DeleteEmptyRows()
Set Tbl = Selected.Tables(1)
    With Tbl
        noOfCol = Tbl.Range.Rows(1).Cells.Count
        With .Range
            For i = .Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
                On Error Resume Next
                If Len(.Cells(i).Range) = 2 Then
                    .Rows(.Cells(i).RowIndex).Delete
                    j = i Mod noOfCol
                    If j = 0 Then j = noOfCol
                End If
            Next i
    End With
    End With

End Sub
```

And it's really close to what I want, but I'm just not sure how to specify empty cells in column 2.
I also tried changing the noOfCol line to:

```
Selection.SetRange Selection.Tables(1).Rows(2).Cells(2).Range.Start, _
Selection.Tables(1).Rows.Last.Cells(2).Range.End
```

But that still deletes rows where any column is empty. I need it to delete only rows where column 2 is empty.
Thanks

Comment: So right now you're doing `For i = .Cells.Count` which is *all* cells in the table. Try doing `With .Columns(2)` on the preceding line, instead of `With .Range`. Untested, and you made need to modify the `Delete` line to `Tbl.Rows(i).Delete`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with all the cells in column is a problem because it's not possible to set a `Range` to a column. A `Range` must be a continguous set of characters in the document. While a column *looks* contiguous, behind the scenes its content is actually not. The characters of a table run from top-left to the right, and top-to-bottom (the rows).

The closest code can get is to select the column then work in the `Selection` object. Or loop the rows.

The following code sample demonstrates how to "loop the rows" - similar to what the code in the question uses. The key here is to use the `Table.Cells` for the loop, with the `For` counter designating the row index and the column number (2) designating the column index.

```
Sub ProcessColTwo()
    Dim tbl As Word.Table
    Dim nrRows As Long, ColToCheck As Long, i As Long
    Dim cellRange As Word.Range

    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    nrRows = tbl.Rows.Count
    ColToCheck = 2

    For i = nrRows To 1 Step -1
        Set cellRange = tbl.Cell(i, ColToCheck).Range
        If Len(cellRange.text) = 2 Then
            cellRange.Rows(1).Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

And here's code that demonstrates using `Selection`

```
Sub ProcessColTwo()
    Dim tbl As Word.Table
    Dim ColToCheck As Long
    Dim cel As Word.Cell

    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    ColToCheck = 2
    tbl.Columns(ColToCheck).Select
    For Each cel In Selection.Cells
        If Len(cel.Range.text) = 2 Then
            cel.Range.Rows(1).Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks! I Went with the second code and changed it to Selection.Tables(1), because it will be called as part of another Sub to refer to a bookmarked table.
Related - I tried to tweak it a bit for another table with values so that if a cell in Column 4 = 0 , delete the row. 
 I just changed 'Len(cel.Range.Text) = 2 Then'   To:

    'If cel.Range.Text = 0 Then'

But it didn't work. Help?

Comment: @Sylvie The problem is that a cell still contains those two characters, plus any you add AND content in Word is always a string, never a number. This should actually be a new question, due to these very basic principles, but try: `="0" & vbCr & Chr(7)` If you want more explanation or a more elegant way to do it, please do post a new question.

Comment: Why do you need to include vbCr and Chr(7)? The table.cell guidance on ms site doesn't explain this.

Comment: @Dan Behind the scenes, a Word table is a succession of characters, not a "table". Similar to HTML, Word must interpret the characters and lay out on the screen accordingly. In the old, binary "Word speak" ANSI 13 + ANSI 7 are interpreted as "end of a table cell", ANSI 13 being a "hidden" paragraph mark inextricably attached to ANSI 7, the actual "end of cell" character. There are always two characters, but someone at Microsoft, in the last decade or so, decided that was confusing for developers. In some circumstances, VBA recognizes the pair as only one character. This is even more confusing!

Answer (score 0):

The code below is for for "each and every" pages after a mail merge [i have used a nested loop ( one for [TABLE] and the other for empty [CELLS])

All codes [respect to: Cindy Meister]

```
  Sub ProcessColTwo()
     Dim pg As Page
     Dim tbl As Word.Table
     Dim ColToCheck As Long
     Dim cel As Word.Cell

       For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
       ColToCheck = 2
       tbl.Columns(ColToCheck).Select

       For Each cel In Selection.Cells
           If Len(cel.Range.Text) = 2 Then
              cel.Range.Rows(1).Delete
           End If
       Next
       Next
  End Sub
```