# Word table cells characters

Tags: vba, ms-word

I put this code together with help from this existing post [Word Macro Remove Rows from Table If Cell Empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53323710/word-macro-remove-rows-from-table-if-cell-empty) but I would like to have an explanation of why cells in word tables have a vbaCr and Chr(7) in them? There is no explanation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.table.cell

```
Sub RemoveEmptyRows()

Dim Tbl As Table
Dim NoRow As Integer
Dim iRow As Long
Dim TRange As Range

Set TRange = ActiveDocument.Content

TRange.Start = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("GroundSummary").Range.Start

For Each Tbl In TRange.Tables

    NoRow = Tbl.Rows.Count
        
    For iRow = NoRow To 1 Step -1
    
        If Tbl.Cell(iRow, 3).Range.Text = "0" & vbCr & Chr(7) Then
        Tbl.Rows(iRow).Delete
        End If
        
    Next iRow
    

Next Tbl


End Sub
```

Comment: It is the end of cell marker. You can make it visible by clicking the Show/Hide button on the Home tab or `ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.ShowAll = True`. If you use Word you need to be aware of all the non-printing characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure is by design. That character pair represents both the end-of-cell and end-of-row marker.

Try:

```
Sub RemoveEmptyRows()
Dim Tbl As Table, iRow As Long
For Each Tbl In ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("GroundSummary").Range.Tables
  With Tbl
    For iRow = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Split(.Cell(iRow, 3).Range.Text, vbCr) = "0" Then
          .Rows(iRow).Delete
        End If
    Next iRow
  End With
Next Tbl
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @macropod. When you say end-of-row does each cell have it's own rows property? The table in question has 5 columns so the end of the cell in column 3  is not the end of the tables row.

Comment: Each cell has an end-of-cell character pair (Chr(13) & Chr(07), which appears as '¤') as the end-of-cell marker and each row uses a duplicate of that character pair as the end-of-row marker - but the end-of-row marker usually isn't visible. Naturally, cells belong to rows and columns, but cells in Word can span multiple rows and columns, as well as having different widths in the same column (you can't do the latter in Excel).