# Tag end-of-cell marker in word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, formatting

I am exploring using word to "capture formatting" when converting to a text file.

The overall aim is to capture custom document structure and format when converting to a text file. i.e to generate a text file that says (BOLD) if the text if bold, or (UNDERLINED) if underlines etc.

Following previous questions, this generally works to generate text files capturing sentences as a while (i.e. not introducing unwanted line breaks) which can then be read using power query.

Ultimately this has proved useful but I have realised that a document's structure and formatting have valuable information that so far is not captured.

I only realised yesterday that it is actually possible using word to find and replace formatting features. Here in the image below, I have used word to recognise if the text is underlined and replace this with the text (HEADER) before it. The same can be done for presumably most formatting marks (e.g. Tab).

[image]

For the most part dynamically tag headers in the Text file which I can then use to create a function in power query to iterate over various similar documents and start separating the text into relevant sections.

This being said I have come across the `end of cell marker` as shown here:

[image]

Initially, I thought it would be feasible to find and replace such markers with another character (`|`), however, it seems that that formatting mark cannot be searched for in the above way.

This being said there is some hope with people seemingly doing similar things using VBA to get `Chr(13)` which is apparently the value for this and recognising it.

I just want to create a script to tag each end of the cell marker with some character.

Comment: They're not {TAB}s are they? You should be able to locate those using Chr(9).

Comment: Unfortunately not. The Tabs are -> which you are right as they are a character I can replace if I want. The circle with a cross on it, i didn't know until yesterday but appears to be an end of cell mark which you cant easily find and replace but seemingly online you can use VBA to do this.

Comment: the circle with the cross is a non-visible character.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64125625 seems to suggest it's a Chr(13) & Chr(7)..?

Comment: Ah yes thanks for this, I found this page earlier but lost it. Yes, you are also right that these are the apparent characters but searching using Ctrl H doesn't work to find and replace them. Need to have some sort of macro which I am currently exploring.

Comment: Given that you're the document to a text file, and text files can't contain tables, you will need to convert the table to text. With ActiveDocument: Do While .Tables.Count > 0: .Tables(1).ConvertToText vbTab, True: Loop: End With

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this answer: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/add-character-before-end-of-cell-marker-in-word/2b7fe2c3-e96e-4d34-a887-b1ddf17d512f

```
'If you want to add the character to only the cell that contains the cursor, use this (see http://www.gmayor.com/installing_macro.htm if needed):

    

Sub AddToSelectedCell()
    Dim cl As Cell

    If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
        Set cl = Selection.Cells(1)
        cl.Range.Text = _
            Left(cl.Range.Text, Len(cl.Range.Text) - 2) _
            & "a"  ' <= the character you want to add
    Else
        MsgBox "Put the cursor in the cell and rerun this macro."
    End If
End Sub

'If you want to add the same character to the end of every cell in the table that contains the cursor, use this instead:

Sub AddToEveryCell()
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim rw As Row
    Dim cl As Cell
    
    If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
        Set tbl = Selection.Tables(1)
        For Each rw In tbl.Rows
            For Each cl In rw.Cells
                cl.Range.Text = _
                    Left(cl.Range.Text, Len(cl.Range.Text) - 2) _
                    & "a"  ' <= the character you want to add
            Next cl
        Next rw
    Else
        MsgBox "Put the cursor in the table and rerun this macro."
    End If
End Sub
```