# VBA Word - Copy Table Cell Text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to compare the first cell in every table to an array and delete the table if the value of the cell is not listed in the array.

When I use `Cell().Range.Text` it is copying some formatting and outputting the text, a new line, and a box that I believe is indicating the border formatting of the cell. [image: Immediate Output]

The macro below is a test to print all values of the first cell in each table.

```
Sub Copy()
    Dim t As Table
    Dim CellText As String
    
    For Each t In ActiveDocument.Tables
    
        CellText = t.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text
        Debug.Print CellText
        
    Next t
    
End Sub
```

The values stored from the table are preventing the comparison from working, and it just deletes every table in the document.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Edit:
For clarification I am asking how to copy cell text without including end of cell markers.

Following a suggestion, I simply deleted the last two characters using the method below.

```
Sub Copy()
    Dim t As Table
    Dim CellText As String
    
    For Each t In ActiveDocument.Tables
    
        CellText = t.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text
        CellText = Left(CellText, Len(CellText) - 2)  'Edited In
        Debug.Print CellText
        
    Next t
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to remove the last two characters from the `CellText` value.  That's the "end of cell" marker.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64125625/word-table-cells-characters